# creat a new variable within several data frames in R

Tags: r, variables, vector, dataframe

I have several data frames *df1, df, 2...., df10*. Columns (variables) are the same in all of them.

I want to create a new variable within each of them. I can easily do it "manually" as follows:

```
df1$newvariable <- ifelse(df1$oldvariable == 999, NA, df1$oldvariable)
```

or, alternatively

```
df1 = transform(df1, df1$newvariable= ifelse(df1$oldvariable==999, NA, df1$oldvariable)))
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to do this in a loop. If I write

```
for (i in names) { #names is the list of dataframes
  i$newvariable <- ifelse(i$oldvariable == 999, NA, i$oldvariable)
}
```

I get the following output

```
Error in i$oldvariable : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 4):

What I'd do is to pool all `data.frame` on to a list and then use `lapply` as follows:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2*10), ncol=2))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2*10), ncol=2))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2*10), ncol=2))
df4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2*10), ncol=2))

# create a list and use lapply
df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
out <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {
    x$id <- 1:nrow(x)
    x
})
```

Now, you'll have all the data.frames with a new column `id` appended and `out` is a list of `data.frames`. You can access each of the data.frames with `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]` etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure I got it, I will study it in detail and express you my comments.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked many times. The `$<-` is not capable of translating that "i" index into either the first or second arguments. The `[[<-` is capable of doing so for the second argument but not the first. You should be learning to use `lapply` and you will probably need to do it with two nested `lapply`'s, one for the list of "names" and the other for each column in the dataframes. The question is incomplete since it lacks specific examples. Make up a set of three dataframes, set some of the values to "999" and provide a list of names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry If my question was incomplete or if I went on a argument treated somewhere else (even though I could not find those questions). I'll reflect on your answer and see if I can come out with some solution.